# Calling new function from element id created in query

Tags: jquery, function, attr

I have an issue while creating a new html select tag called from a previous select tag in jQuery.

So I start with:

```
$('#tab11').click(function() {

    var columns = [
        {val:'id', text:'id', id:'id'},
        {val:'display_name', text:'display_name', id:'display_name'},
        {val:'short_name', text:'short_name', id:'short_name'}
    ];  

    $('#columns').html('');
    $('#condition').html('');

    var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#columns')
                           .css({backgroundColor:'#8B0000',
                                 color:'white',
                                 border:'inset 1px',
                                 borderColor:'#8B0000',
                                 width:'130'});

    $(columns).each(function() {
       sel.append($("<option>").attr({value:this.val, id:this.id})
                               .text(this.text)); 
    });

});
```

Until here everything works fine, so now i want to call a function like

```
$('#id').click(function() {
    // some code here
});
```

whereby `#id` is equal to my id in the option tag created in the function above.
My problem is that this function is not executed by clicking on the option with the `id='#id'` etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanx to all who try to help me.
cheers.

Comment: WHy do you need a click on option? you can't handle it in the select's change event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `change` event on select, i guess click event will not work for `option` elements.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrpkf/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#columns').html('');
    $('#condition').html('');

    var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#columns').css({
        backgroundColor: '#8B0000',
        color: 'white',
        border: 'inset 1px',
        borderColor: '#8B0000',
        width: '130'
    }).change(handleChange);

    $(columns).each(function () {
        sel.append($("<option>").attr({
            value: this.val,
            id: this.id,

        }).text(this.text))
    });
});

function handleChange() {
    alert($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: ok thx a lot this works but I want to execute a different function for each of the option tags! How do I realize that?

Comment: You can get the value of option inside the select change and execute them based on the value. If you can give me a sample fiddle i can write up and show you.

Comment: Well atleast I want to execute the very same function just with other variables in the columns[] array! So do you mean something like if($("<option>").val() == 'myvalue') {insert code here} ??

Comment: yes this helps a lot i'll try this out. Thanks so much again for your help! Good Night ;)